# Is my server overloaded?

Tags: linux, load, average

I've just pushed a new server under prodution and his load average seems to be very high, but I've read a lot of stuff about multiprocessors and load average and I can't tell if my server is overloaded right now...

It displays an average load of : **15,57, 15,64, 15,60**

In my /proc/cpuinfo, I have **eight entries** of this type :

```
processor   : 7
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5355  @ 2.66GHz
stepping    : 11
microcode   : ***
cpu MHz     : 2000.000
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 4
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 7
initial apicid  : 7
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : ***
bogomips    : 5320.06
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 38 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Does that mean I can go to a load average of 32? (8*4).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [particular processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/28035) has 4 cores and is not hyperthreaded, so you have 2 physical CPUs each with 4 cores.

With 2 x 4 cores, you can execute 8 processes at any one time.

Therefore as soon as your load average is above 8, you are queuing processes.

Your box is "overloaded" as you have more processes trying to use the CPU then you can handle. Whether this is OK is up to you - it might still be serving requests within an acceptable time frame.

Have a look at `mpstat -P ALL` which will show the the CPU usage of each of your cores. You should have 8 entries (and an all average). `sar` is also a good tool for investigating this kind of issue.

To give you a better understanding on how to read `cpuinfo`:

- `physical Id` is the id of the physical CPU chip. Starting at 0.
- `cpu
  cores` is the amount of cores in this physical CPU.
- `core id` is the
  id of the core for this physical CPU.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for this clear explaination ! We'll have a look at these tools

Comment: load could be high because of i/o as well. you assume things are cpu bound.

Comment: @mnagel Agreed - one of the reasons I really like `mpstat`. It breaks down CPU usage over all cores and includes things like `iowait` and `sys` usage - a very informative tool.

Answer (score 0):

No, it means that each of your 8 processors is overloaded with 1 idle process because you have 8 processors and your load is 16 on average.

Comment: What about the "cpu cores: 4" for each processor?

Comment: As @Will said, you have 4 cores (cpu cores) * 2 physical CPUs (physical id).
For more details : [link](http://www.richweb.com/cpu_info).

You can use ̀`mpstat`, `vmstat`, `iotop`, `atop` and `smem` to determine why your server  is in overload

Comment: Thanks! We'll have a look at these tools.